# Is there a way to give parts of the local namespace to an importee?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

a.py:

```
import b
import c
...
import z

class Foo(object):
    ...
```

Each of thoses module B-Z needs to use class foo.

Is some way, like importing, which allows indirect access (e.g. via an object) to all values of all modules A-Z, while still allowing each module B-Z access to A's namespace (e.g. foo).

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking. Can you post some code to illustrate?

Comment: After editing the post to be as clear as possible, I still cannot understand. You should edit the question and say what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

No. They must each in turn import `A` themselves.

Comment: @JBernardo: Not in Python. It can be resolved if done properly.

Answer (score 2):

I still cannot tell what you are trying to do or even asking, but this is my best guess:

Normally, just use classic imports.

**IF** a module is growing too large, or if you have an extremely good reason to split things up but desire to share the same namespace, you can "hoist" values into a dummy namespace. For example if I had `widget.Foo` and `widget.Bar` and wanted them in different files, but I wanted to be able to type `Foo` and `Bar` in each file, I would normally have to `from widget import Foo` and `from widget import Bar`. If you have MANY of these files (foo.py,bar.py,baz.py,...,zeta.py) it can get a bit unwieldy. Thus you can improve your situation by importing them only once, in `widget/__init__.py`, and then going `from foo import *, from bar import *, ...` in each folder just **once**, and going `from widget import *` only once in each module. And you're done!... well... almost...

This gets you into a circular import scenario, which you have to be extremely careful of: [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-circular-or-cyclic-imports) It will be fine for example if you reference `Bar` in a function in `foo.py`, everything is fine because you don't immediately use the value. However if you do `x = Bar` in `foo.py` then the value may not have been defined yet!

sidenote: You can programatically import using the `__import__` function. If you couple this with `os.walk` then you can avoid having to type `from ... import *` for each file in your widget folder. This is a critical and necessary step to avoid bugs down the line.